# How to save data in my file from an custom header sent from termimal with CURL

Tags: ruby, https, header, sinatra

Using Sinatra, I need to run my server and send data from a URL from the terminal with CURL. This is the code:

```
curl -XGET -H "permiso: soy-un-token-secreto" "http://localhost:4567/"
```

I need to save the String "soy-un-token-secreto" in a variable with the name `@permiso`.

I wrote:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  if params[:permiso] && params[:permiso] == "soy-un-token-secreto"
    "Si lo logramos!"
  else
    "Sin Permiso"
  end
end
```

Comment: Use [postman](https://www.postman.com/) instead of curl,  it's much easier to use

Comment: Thank you friend but I need to use CURL to solve this challenge.  I am going to take your answer into account for future projects.

Comment: Hi Diego, welcome to SO.  I think we need to know more.  Can you please edit your question to tell us what you are having trouble with?  Does the code cause an exception?  Does it run but generates an incorrect result?  Are you having trouble making Sinatra do what you need?  We don't know how to help you without knowing more.  It would be especially helpful to see a curl command with its result.

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending it as a parameter, but as a header. Use this instead of `params[:permiso]`:

```
request.env['HTTP_PERMISO']
```

Additional note: There is no purpose in doing

```
params[:permiso] && params[:permiso] == "soy-un-token-secreto"
```

It is equivalent to

```
params[:permiso] == "soy-un-token-secreto"`
```

since `"soy-un-token-secreto"` cannot be equal to `nil` or `false`.

Comment: Thank you very much Amadan,  just what I was looking for.

Comment: @DIEGOARMANDOCARDENAS "[What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773)"